# Who provides client id and client secret with Identity Server 4?

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, asp.net-identity, identityserver4, openid-connect

I'm learning oAuth2.0 and how to use Identity Server 4 in apps and I have one doubt here.

When we are creating our app with Identity Server 4 and running it locally (it's not yet deployed anywhere), we define our Client ID and Client Secret.

What happens when we deploy app somewhere?

Do we get client ID and client secret from that service we deployed to, and we put it somewhere in our configuration?

Or we put our client ID and client secret that we defined to that service we deployed our app on?
I'm not sure how does this work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The primary job of IdentityServer(IS4) is to manage the identity of the users. It is responsible for authentication and authorization (if claims are configured in it). The [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49701689/identityserver-4-confused-on-how-it-all-works) is a very detailed explanation of it.

To be honest, I myself found IS4 very confusing when I came across it. I was new to C# and suddenly my employer asked me to deal with it. However over time, I realized its beauty and its universal flexibility. You should check out [this series](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fhfvbl_KbWo&list=PLOeFnOV9YBa7dnrjpOG6lMpcyd7Wn7E8V&ab_channel=RawCodingRawCoding) to know more about it (and identity management in C# in general).

To answer your question, you will not only deploy IS4, you will also deploy your Client (API or MVC app). Your client will **rely** on idenityserver for authentication. This client will be configured by you into the IS4. If you are developing both, you will have to configure the client who will consume the tokens and the IS4. If you are going to work only on client then you just have to give the client id and secret to the IS4 developer and that person will configure. And if you are doing both, then you have to establish your client as a permissible client inside IS4. These configurations are generally stored in a C# class for dev purposes and moved to a table (migrations of which come with the IS4) where they can be added or removed very easily.

One last tip, please remember that you cannot learn it as fast as you learn other stacks. It's something that's extremely flexible and hence has too many configuration requirements. It's ok if you take time to understand it. Give it a honest try.